# Why aren't the child nodes of this paragraph attribute being displayed?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am new to JavaScript, and I was putting some code on an editor to test it out.

I am trying to dynamically create elements by appending child nodes to a "p" attribute, but I am not seeing these child nodes displayed. Could you please explain why, and how I can make all of the nodes to be displayed?

Here is the code:

```html
<html> 
<head> 
<title>t1</title> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    function addNode() { 
    var newP = document.createElement("p"); 
        var textNode = document.createTextNode(" This is a new text node"); 
        newP.appendChild(textNode); 
    document.getElementById("firstP").appendChild(newP); 
  } 
</script> </head> 
<body> <p id="firstP">firstP<p> </body> 
</html>
```

Here is the output: `firstP`

I was expecting to get:

```
firstP
p
This is a new text node
```

UPDATE: I accepted the answer that worked. Also realized that I was supposed to expect the output to be:

```
firstP
This is a new text node
```

Comment: Your desired output is the result of the `addNode` function. Right now you've only defined what that function should do, but you're not calling it anywhere. So the function is never executed and the new text node is never created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made typo error and child node need to be added to a `p` parent tag, so inserting the `p` tags into a `div` tag is better, also call the `addNode` function, this will work ;-)

```html
<html>
<head> 
<title>t1</title> 
</head> 
<body>
    <div id="firstPContainer">
        <p>firstP</p>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
    function addNode() { 
        var newP = document.createElement("p"); 
            var textNode = document.createTextNode(" This is a new text node"); 
            newP.appendChild(textNode); 
            document.getElementById("firstPContainer").appendChild(newP); 
    }
    addNode();
</script>
</body> 
</html>
```